# Clickable textview link

Tags: android, hyperlink, webview, textview, clickable

How can i create a clickable `textview` link to open up in webview?

The textview link i want it to be clickable is [`http://d2d.tp.edu.sg/d2d/web/advstandingenq.aspx`](http://d2d.tp.edu.sg/d2d/web/advstandingenq.aspx).
I programmed it to be able to open the webview upon launching the app.

```
public class Hellowebview extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hellowebview);

    mWebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www-eng.tp.edu.sg/eng_met_home");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewclient());
    }

    private class HelloWebViewclient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview,String url)
        {
            webview.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode,KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())
        {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hellowebview, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>"+"open link"+"</u> "));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

and use

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        //ur code to open webview
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below Code for that, it may help you.

```
TextView mTxtViewPreview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTxtViewPreview);
mTxtViewPreview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://www-eng.tp.edu.sg/eng_met_home\">Click to View Invoice</a> "));
mTxtViewPreview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```